# apscheduler: returned more than one DjangoJobExecution -- it returned 2

Tags: python, django, apscheduler

**In my proyect scheduler return this error in the execute job, help me please**

this is my error in cosole, then execute the program

```
Error notifying listener

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\angel\project\venv\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\schedulers\base.py", line 836, in _dispatch_event
    cb(event)
  File "C:\Users\angel\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django_apscheduler\jobstores.py", line 53, in handle_submission_event
    DjangoJobExecution.SENT,
  File "C:\Users\angel\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django_apscheduler\models.py", line 157, in atomic_update_or_create
    job_id=job_id, run_time=run_time
  File "C:\Users\angel\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 412, in get
    (self.model._meta.object_name, num)
django_apscheduler.models.DjangoJobExecution.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one DjangoJobExecution -- it returned 2!
```

This is my code

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Runs apscheduler."
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(timezone=settings.TIME_ZONE, daemon=True)
    scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), "default")

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.scheduler.add_job(
            delete_old_job_executions,
            'interval', seconds=5,
            id="delete_old_job_executions",
            max_instances=1,
            replace_existing=True
        )

        try:
            logger.info("Starting scheduler...")
            self.scheduler.start()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            logger.info("Stopping scheduler...")
            self.scheduler.shutdown()
            logger.info("Scheduler shut down successfully!")
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you're still having this issue. I have same error and found your question. Turned out this happens only in dev environment.

Because `python3 manage.py runserver` starts two processes by default, the code
seems to register two job records and find two entries at next run time.

With `--noreload` option, it starts only one scheduler thread and works well. As name implies, it won't reload changes you make automatically though.

`python3 manage.py runserver --noreload`

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you're still having this issue. i think you can use socket , socket can use this issue.

look this  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxvZL.png)

Comment: Please refrain from using images for showing code